# Delphi 11 and WinAPI.WinSvc (function EnumServiceState)

Tags: delphi

I used the code below to get a list of Windows services. It works well for Delphi 10.2.3 and earlier:

```
uses WinSvc;

//-------------------------------------
// Get a list of services
//
// return TRUE if successful
//
// sMachine:
//   machine name, ie: \SERVER
//   empty = local machine
//
// dwServiceType
//   SERVICE_WIN32,
//   SERVICE_DRIVER or
//   SERVICE_TYPE_ALL
//
// dwServiceState
//   SERVICE_ACTIVE,
//   SERVICE_INACTIVE or
//   SERVICE_STATE_ALL
//
// slServicesList
//   TStrings variable to storage
//
function ServiceGetList(
  sMachine : string;
  dwServiceType,
  dwServiceState : DWord;
  slServicesList : TStrings )
  : boolean;
const
  //
  // assume that the total number of
  // services is less than 4096.
  // increase if necessary
  cnMaxServices = 4096;

type
  TSvcA = array[0..cnMaxServices]
          of TEnumServiceStatus;
  PSvcA = ^TSvcA;
          
var
  //
  // temp. use
  j : integer;

  //
  // service control
  // manager handle
  schm          : SC_Handle;

  //
  // bytes needed for the
  // next buffer, if any
  nBytesNeeded,

  //
  // number of services
  nServices,

  //
  // pointer to the
  // next unread service entry
  nResumeHandle : DWord;

  //
  // service status array
  ssa : PSvcA;
begin
  Result := false;

  // connect to the service
  // control manager
  schm := OpenSCManager(
    PChar(sMachine),
    Nil,
    SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

  // if successful...
  if(schm > 0)then
  begin
    nResumeHandle := 0;

    New(ssa);

    EnumServicesStatus(
      schm,
      dwServiceType,
      dwServiceState,
      ssa^[0],
      SizeOf(ssa^),
      nBytesNeeded,
      nServices,
      nResumeHandle );

    //
    // assume that our initial array
    // was large enough to hold all
    // entries. add code to enumerate
    // if necessary.
    //
    
    for j := 0 to nServices-1 do
    begin
      slServicesList.
        Add( StrPas(
          ssa^[j].lpDisplayName ) );
    end;

    Result := true;

    Dispose(ssa);

    // close service control
    // manager handle
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);
  end;
end;
```

To get a list of all Windows services into a ListBox named `ListBox1`:

```
ServiceGetList( '',
  SERVICE_WIN32,
  SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
  ListBox1.Items );
```

I tried to use the same code in Delphi 10.4 and Delphi 11, but there is a problem with the `EnumServicesStatus` function:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(145): E2010 Incompatible types: 'LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUSW' and '_ENUM_SERVICE_STATUSW'

When I tried `LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUSW` instead `TEnumServiceStatus`:

```
type
  TSvcA = array[0..cnMaxServices]
          of LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUSW;// instead TEnumServiceStatus;
```

I got an 'access violation' error.

Maybe the point is in the external function in `Winapi.WinSvc.pas`:

```
function EnumServicesStatus;    external advapi32 name 'EnumServicesStatusW';
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, rather than just out-of-context code in snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to pre-allocate such a large array. You can't assume how many services the PC actually has installed. Let `EnumServicesStatus()` tell you how much to allocate for the array.

Also, you have to account for the possibility that you may have to call `EnumServicesStatus()` multiple times to get all of the statuses.

Now, regarding the compiler issue - the actual `EnumServiceStatus()` API wants a pointer to an array of `ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS` records (aliased as `TEnumServiceStatus` in the `WinSvc` unit), not an array of `LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS` pointers. In earlier versions of Delphi, the `Winsvc` unit declared `EnumServiceStatusW()` to take a `var` reference to the 1st `ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS` in the array. But apparently it has since been re-declared to instead take a pointer to the 1st `ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS`, to match the actual API.

So, with that said, try something more like this:

```
uses
  WinSvc;

{$IFDEF CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS}
  {$IF CompilerVersion >= 34}
    {$DEFINE lpServices_Param_Is_Pointer}
  {$IFEND}
{$ENDIF}

function ServiceGetList(
  const sMachine : string;
  dwServiceType,
  dwServiceState : DWord;
  slServicesList : TStrings )
  : Boolean;
var
  j : integer;
  schm : SC_Handle;
  nBytesNeeded,
  nServices,
  nResumeHandle : DWord;
  buffer : array of Byte;
  ssa, ss : PEnumServiceStatus;
begin
  Result := False;

  schm := OpenSCManager(
    PChar(sMachine),
    nil,
    SC_MANAGER_CONNECT or SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);

  if (schm <> 0) then
  try
    nResumeHandle := 0;
    if not EnumServicesStatus(
      schm,
      dwServiceType,
      dwServiceState,
      {$IFDEF lpServices_Param_Is_Pointer}nil{$ELSE}PEnumServiceStatus(nil)^{$ENDIF},
      0,
      nBytesNeeded,
      nServices,
      nResumeHandle) then
    begin
      if (GetLastError() <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) and (GetLastError() <> ERROR_MORE_DATA) then
      begin
        Exit;
      end;
      SetLength(buffer, nBytesNeeded);
      ssa := PEnumServiceStatus(buffer);
      if not EnumServicesStatus(
        schm,
        dwServiceType,
        dwServiceState,
        ssa{$IFNDEF lpServices_Param_Is_Pointer}^{$ENDIF},
        Length(buffer),
        nBytesNeeded,
        nServices,
        nResumeHandle) then
      begin
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
    if (nServices > 0) then
    begin
      ss := ssa;
      for j := 0 to nServices-1 do
      begin
        slServicesList.Add(ss.lpDisplayName);
        Inc(ss);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy, Thank you so much
In Delphi 10.2.3 and earlier editions there was no problem with (array of ENUM_SERVICE_STATUSW)
Now with delphi 11 it wants a parameter lpServices must be  LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUSW .. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-enumservicesstatusw
So I don't know how use EnumServiceStatusW() ..

Comment: Thank you very much Remy, for the valuable explanation,
But there is still a problem at `slServicesList.Add(ssa[j].lpDisplayName)` .. Array type required, I tried to fix it with :
`slServicesList.Add(ssa{$IFNDEF lpServices_Param_Is_Pointer}^[X]{$ELSE}[X]{$ENDIF}.lpDisplayName)`, same error

Comment: @AbdurRahman my earlier example was assuming PointerMath was enabled, but apparently that wasn't the case, so I have updated my example to remove that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your kindness and patience,
`ServiceGetList( '',   SERVICE_WIN32,  SERVICE_STATE_ALL,  ListBox1.Items );`
 The function is supposed to give a list of installed services in Windows, But the list is completely empty

Comment: @AbdurRahman is `ServiceGetList()` returning `False`? You are just going to have to step through the code with the debugger to find out what is going on.

Comment: ServiceGetList() returns True even if condition (if (schm <> 0) ignored, and  (try .. finally) removed .. the parameter `nServices` still =0 ..

Comment: "*the parameter `nServices` still =0*" - that should not be possible if `EnumServicesStatus()` returns non-zero, or returns 0 with error code `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. Again, step through the code with the debugger, what EXACTLY is happening at each stage? Where does it actually deviate from your expectation?

Comment: code compiled without errors, `nServices=1700724` by default at the beginning of the code, `EnumServicesStatus()` "external function" gives `nServices`  zero value, so the condition `(nServices > 0)` is false, I think exactly the problem is in `ssa` and `ss` variable type, regards

Comment: @AbdurRahman The only way I can see `ServiceGetList()` returning True with no entries added to `slServicesList` is if `EnumServicesStatus()` returns zero, `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, and both `nServices` and `nResumeHandle` are 0. But that combination of values conflicts with the `EnumServicesStatus()` documentation. Unless the documentation is wrong and `GetLastError()` actually returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA` when `ssa` is nil instead of `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` as documented. This is what your debugging needs to discover. What is *actually* happening on every function call?

Comment: @AbdurRahman whatever. I have rewritten my example to stop calling `EnumServicesStatus()` in a loop

Comment: Sorry for the delay and lack of focus, actually `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA` = 234, your last update is perfect, and previous code with loop also works but needs to modify the condition `if (GetLastError() <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) and (GetLastError() <> ERROR_MORE_DATA) then Exit` , So Thank you so much Remy for your time and patience, Regards